# TestFlight install says "Incompatible with Apple Watch"

Tags: ios, watchkit, testflight

We have a user who is installing our application for the initial time on TestFlight and she gets the following alert:

[image: TestFlight Apple Watch alert]

**Alert title:** `Incompatible With Apple Watch`

**Alert description:** `The app can be tested but isn't compatible with your Apple Watch. If you install the app, you'll delete its Apple Watch app and data.`

All the "unique" attributes I can come up with:

1. This version bumps our watchOS minimum version to `3.0`.
2. She's a new TestFlight installer. She was just added as of today.
3. She's using a non-Series 2 Apple Watch on the latest OS (`3.1.3`).

**Any ideas why this alert is presented?**

Comment: +1 however I've been testing with testflight for a while and never got this message earlier. Also, even though it shows this message, the watch app installs just fine.

Comment: I seemingly had no issues just pressing "Install" as well. I mostly ask because it's confusing to our beta users.